# tkinter exit/quit/killing function threading out of mainloop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have this script that execute a long running function out of/before the main class/loop in tkinter
and there is a button i created to quit the program completely using root.destroy() but it close the gui and the function keep running in the console or even as a background process after i created the executable file.

How to solve this issue?

snippets of my script:

```
 from tkinter import *
 import threading             

def download():
    #downloading a video file
def stop(): # stop button to close the gui and should terminate the download function too
   root.destroy()

class 
...
...
...
def downloadbutton():
    threading.Thread(target=download).start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the thread a daemon to have it die when the main thread dies.

```
def downloadbutton():
    t = threading.Thread(target=download)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

def download():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('tick tock')

def stop(): # stop button to close the gui and should terminate the download function too
   root.destroy()

def downloadbutton():
    t = threading.Thread(target=download)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(text = "Start", command=downloadbutton)
btn.pack()
btn = tk.Button(text = "Stop", command=stop)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Novel, I used the code you provided and the gui closed but the download function still running in the console
I'm searching now for other similar questions related to threading daemons...

Comment: @SarahJohnson it works for me. I edited my answer to include a [mcve], please do the same for your question.

Comment: I just discovered i had a messed up and excessive test lines of codes calling the button functions and such and i commented them out
and it finally worked!
Thank you very much Novel, I greatly Apperciated it...you saved me alot of time and effort
~Love & Light

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way I could implement it in one line?

I am using this so far:

```
b_start = Button(app,text='Start',padx=8, pady=20, command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=filters).start())
```